# UWP MediaPlayerElement: An unknown error occurred

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app that is using the media element to present video and audio files.  When I navigate away from the MediaElements in the app and navigate back, I frequently get "Error: An unknown error occurred" instead of the video/audio.  It looks like this:

[image: Broken MediaElement]

Sometimes, I can navigate back after getting this error and it will load fine.
I am populating the MediaSource by passing a StorageFile using `MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile` and is only getting set once.  I'm not getting any exceptions in the application and I don't see anything in the Event Viewer.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

XAML

```
                        <MediaPlayerElement Source="{x:Bind MediaSource}" 
                            Width="400"
                            MaxWidth="400"
                            AutoPlay="False"
                            AreTransportControlsEnabled="true"

                            HorizontalAlignment="{x:Bind Alignment, Converter={StaticResource AlignmentConverter}}"
                                        >
                        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                            <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True"
                                                    IsZoomButtonVisible="{x:Bind IsVideo}"
                                                    IsFullWindowButtonVisible="{x:Bind IsVideo}"/>
                        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                    </MediaPlayerElement>
```

Comment: It is hard to reproduce your issue without detailed code, could you provide a minimal code project which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I'm going to try to get a minimal project that reproduces this for you.  It is taking some time and there are more moving parts than I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain and an MSDN ticket, we figured this out.  It turns out that when the `MediaPlayerElement` was being recycled it wasn't getting disposed properly and so the next time the application tried to load from the same `MediaSource` it would break with this error.

The key was to set the `Source` property of the element to `null` in the `ContainerContentChanging` event for the parent element of the `MediaPlayerElement` for the elements that were marked for recycling.